# Finding $A^{2017}$ using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$, which is $P(A)= -A^3-2A^2 +3A-8=0$. how do i find $A^{2017}$ now? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you sure about the polynomial? Where does this problem come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways:

1. Divide $X^{2017}$ by $ -X^3-2X^2 +3X-8$ and take the remainder.
2. Write $A^n = a_n A^2 + b_n A + c_n I$. Then $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1},c_{n+1})=(-2a_n+b_n,3a_n+c,-8a_n)$.
3. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be the three complex roots of $-X^3-2X^2 +3X-8$. They are distinct. Therefore, $A=PDP^{-1}$, where $D=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$. Then $A^{2017}=PD^{2017}P^{-1}$, and $D^{2017}=diag(\lambda_1^{2017},\lambda_2^{2017},\lambda_3^{2017})$. However, there is no nice formula for $\lambda_i$, let alone for their powers.

At least, option 2 is easily done with a simple computer program (but you may need arbitrary precision).

Comment: But [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialQuotientRemainder%5Bx%5E2017,(+-x%5E3-2x%5E2+%2B3x-8),x%5D) does not know how to do it...

Comment: I used maple and got huge coefficients for the reminder. There must be a better way, but I'm not an algebraist.. ^^

Comment: I tried the diagonalization way too, but those roots are just from hell. This is a very impolite characteristic polynomial.. :p

Comment: Passing by, I saw this exerise. WA Works with $X^{350}$, but not with $X^{360}$ (at least in my computer). Anyway we can think like this: $\frac{210}{6}=\frac{35\cdot6}{6}=\frac{35}{6}\cdot6=(5+\frac{5}{6})\cdot6=30+\frac{30}{6}=... $. Just an idea.